# iterating through classes to hide/show

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have several divs with class "image" and several with class "thumbnail" (both can be variable based on amount user adds but always thumbnail is generated using image and always is in same order so first thumb come from first image) I have all the thumb divs being hidden but the first one already using:

```
  $('.image:not(:first)').hide();
```

I want to iterate through thumbnail class and have it show second image and hide others if I click 2nd thumb, 3rd image if I click 3rd thumb, etc.

how would I do this in jQuery?

Comment: It sounds like the functionality that you want is similar to a [carousel](http://www.agilecarousel.com/flavor_2.htm). I'd suggest looking at some jquery carousel plugins.

Comment: I do want Carousel, but with all the dynamic content, it's hard to find something that accounts for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create some means of linking the two together. In this example I use the element's index. You can then use CSS classes to toggle the display state.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZCuYM/1/

```
$('.thumb').click( function() {
    //switch active thumb
    $('.thumb.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    //switch active image
    $('.image.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.image').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
});​
```

Comment: Ok, this obviously works in your example. for some reason I cannot get it to work locally. I have some of these elements nested in other elements, would this affect how the code works? I can alert so jQuery is working perfect, but the .click function doesn't seem to work. Even tried just .click on other elements, and doesn't seem to work?

Comment: This is how I would debug. First, put an alert in the thumb click function. Then I would ask myself these questions. Do you have an element with class `thumb`? Next, when you click on a `thumb`, is there anything inside of thumb that would prevent a click from registering? For example another click handler with `preventDefault()` or `cancelBubble()`. Next, is there anything over it that would steal the click event? For example, an invisible element. If you can post a link to your site I can take a look, but debugging through the interwebs is no fun!

Comment: ahh. I was using alert, but it wasn't working because it was outside an already existing .ready function. didn't realize everything had to be inside it, silly me. this works perfect now though. thanks for the extra help, you saved me a huge headache!

Comment: ok actually, so it I do have it working now all except one thing, everything is dynamically generated so I cannot add active class via HTML. I tried adding .image:first-child { display: inline} before.image { display: none; } to show first element, and it works except when I click on other images, it doesn't hide first one, everything else works perfect though/

Comment: Just call `$('img:first').addClass('active');` after the content is created. http://jsfiddle.net/ZCuYM/2/ . The class is the trick, not the display property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on the second thumb and show the second image while hiding others, the code below should do:

```
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="thumb"></div>
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="thumb"></div>

$('.thumb').click(function() {
   $('.image').hide();
   $(this).prev('.image').show();
});
```

In this case when you click a .thumb, all .image elements are hidden and the .image before the currently clicked .thumb is shown. If you add elements in realtime, you might consider using **.on()** for the click event